# Feedparser not seeing description element value in RSS feed

Tags: python-2.7, xml-parsing, rss, feedparser

Feedparser parses the bulk of this feed just fine, but for some reason will not return a value for the description element.

Feed: http://bigpopfunpodcast.libsyn.com/rss

The code I'm testing with:

```
show = feedparser.parse('http://bigpopfunpodcast.libsyn.com/rss')              
if 'description' in show.feed:
    description = show.feed.description
else:
    description = 'No description found'
```

This code returns an empty string. When I print the contents of show to see the results of the parse, there’s no description element. But when I view the RSS data myself, the description element is clearly there. The code should return:

"Big Pop Fun with Tom Wilson is a podcast dedicated to pop, and the lives lived within its gentle influence, or tightening grasp, or soul crushing evil claws, depending on who you are. Unapologetically big and fun, Tom has lived a life that the world has seen through pop cultural lenses, and you can keep them on or take them off, but he's going to keep going anyway. Enjoy!"

Feed: http://cashinginwithtjmiller.libsyn.com/rss

The code returns the description on this feed, but I don't see a difference the two feeds that explains the inconsistency.

I’m not able to find an explaination, after much searching around. Does anyone know a solution to this? Thanks in advance.